# How to find my answer on a deleted question?

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-questions

Sometimes a question that I answered is deleted. I know that I can find the deleted question and see my answer if I had saved question's URL or marked question as a favorite, but sure I have no reason to do it beforehand because I don't know which question will be deleted.

Is it possible to find deleted questions that I answered?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. You can try checking the Google-cached version of your profile to see if the answer is still linked there, or pull it from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if it made it into the previous data dump. If you're desperate you can ask a moderator to check for you (they can see deleted answers on a user's profile page)

Comment: Probably the question was not deleted but made community wiki. I notice (ex in manually recalculated reputation) that something related to my answers happened, but don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

If your answer got any comment, you might find it in your [global Inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/89267?tab=inbox).

From what I remember, it keep comments on deleted posts but it might been "fixed" since.

Otherwise Michael answer pretty much covers everything else.